# Algorithm suggestion for Matrix in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Not sure if the title is appropriate, please edit as you wish :-)

I have a series of html/css which create a layout described below.

Every cell is a div with a numbered class in the html (cell_1, cell_2, and so on).

When the page load cell numbered 1 is highlighted in the first grid.

A User can navigate among cell using the keyboard arrows key. When pressing ENTER user can jump to another grid at position 1.

Navigation is allowed only to certain cells accordingly to current cell location (cell highlighted) with some logic (described below).

The logic for each grid is described below..where

```
n= do nothing
bar= do nothing
y-2= means move to cell 2
```

My question is: instead to use a series of hard-coded `if` or `case` statements for each grid,
could you please suggested me smart way to have **reusable logic** (Matrix or similar possible in js)?

Please provide a short example or a link to some resource if is possible.
Any alternative ways to solve this approach are very welcome thanks.

---

```
  EXAMPLE LOGIC:
    grid type: 5x
    +--------+------+-------+
    +        +  2   +    4  +
    +   1    +------+-------+
    +        +  3   +    5  +
    +--------+------+-------+
    cell  up     down    left   right
      1   n      bar     n      y-2
      2   n      y-3     y-1    y-4
      3   y-2    bar     y-1    y-5
      4   n      y-5     y-2    n
      5   y-4    bar     y-3    n


    grid type: 7x
    +--------+------+-------+-------+
    +   1    +      3       +   6   +
    +------- +------+-------+-------+
    +   2    +  4   +   5   +   7   +
    +--------+------+-------+-------+
    cell  up     down    left   right
      1   n      y-2     n      y-3
      2   y-1    bar     n      y-4
      3   n      y-4     y-1    y-6
      4   y-3    bar     y-2    y-5
      5   y-3    bar     y-4    y-7
      6   n      y-7     y-3    n
      7   y-6    bar     y-5    n

    ///////////////////////
    grid type: 4x
    +--------+------+-------+-------+
    +        +      +       +       +
    +   1    +  2   +   3   +   4   +
    +        +      +       +       +
    +--------+------+-------+-------+
    cell  up     down    left   right
      1   n      bar     n      y-2
      2   n      bar     y-1    y-3
      3   n      bar     y-2    y-4
      4   n      bar     y-3    n
```

Comment: Can you post also some html and css?

Comment: sorry I do not have the html/css right now, I just would need a general conceptual solution to be applies in details later on. Thanks for commenting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There will be a limit to how reusable you can design this.  If you want each grid to be different, you're going to have to separately define each grid with all of its connectivity.  Given that, though, it's not very hard to abstract.

- Each grid contains a series of cells.
- Each cell has some value for up, down, left, right.

So put this into an object containing other objects, for example:

```
var gridType5 = {
    cells = {
        1: { up: "n", down: "bar", left: "n", right: "2" }, // easier without the "y-", but we can add it if you want
        2: { up: "n", down: "3", left: "1", right: "4" },
        3: { up: "2", down: "bar", left: "1", right: "5" },
        4: { up: "n", down: "5", left: "2", right: "n" },
        5: { up: "4", down: "bar", left: "3", right: "n" }
    }
};

var grids = {
    5: gridType5,
    4: gridType4,
    7: gridType7
};
```

Then, given whatever cell and grid the user is in, you only have one movement logic:

```
function checkMove(currentGrid, currentCell, keypress) {
    var value = grids[currentGrid].cells[currentCell].keypress;
    if (value == "bar" || value == "n") {
        return value;
    }
    return grids[currentGrid].cells[value];
}
```

That's the basic idea.  You can modify the logic, e.g. if you truly don't need the "bar" or "n" values, you can change modify your abstraction:

- Each grid contains a series of cells.
- Each cell has a set of neighbors.

Which would make your cells look like:

```
        2: { neighbors: {down: 3, right: 4}},
```

and your checkMove look like:

```
function checkMove(currentGrid, currentCell, keypress) {
    var newCell = grids[currentGrid].cells[currentCell].neighbors[keypress];
    if (newCell) {
        return grids[currentGrid].cells[newCell];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is solution which doesn't use any additional data structure, pseudo-code:

1. `top_x`, `top_y`, `width`, `height` = get the boundries of clicked element
2. case `direction`:

   `left:`

   new_x = `top_x` - `w` from left boundries (where (`border_width` + `paddigns`) < `w`< `the smallest box width`)

   `right`: ...

   ...
3. use `document.elementFromPoint` using `new_x` and `new_y` to find the correct `div` to light it up. If the `div` didn't changed, `goto @2`.

PS. The easiest way would be just use properly tags like old-fashioned `<table>`.

PS2. Of course, don't use `"goto"` instruction :)

Comment: This is a cool way to do it without needing any extra data structures, so +1.  My only issue with it is if any of the grids are defined where a box bigger than one unit has its directions not choose the top or left neighbor.  (e.g. you're ok with 5x/cell1/right and 7x/cell3/down, but maybe not in other grids the OP hasn't shown.)

Comment: Oh right, I forgot about `while` till we changed our `<div>`.

Comment: Thanks ProblemFactory, I would accept both answers but unfortunately it is not allowed :-). Very interesting approach so +1 +1